# How sendgrid work without email password?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, smtp, sendgrid

I use this tutorial [Microsoft Email Configuration for .net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=netcore-cli),

Everything works correctly, something I wonder. In the traditional smtp setup we were specifying the password along with the email, why doesn't the SendGrid system require a password for email?

Traditional smtp setup we enter password with email as below.

```
var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = "smtp.gmail.com", // set your SMTP server name here
    Port = 587, // Port 
    EnableSsl = true,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password")
};
```

But I didn't understand this tutorial SendGrid does not want password just only want mail adress.

```
var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
var msg = new SendGridMessage()
{
   From = new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Joe Smith"),
   Subject = subject,
   PlainTextContent = message,
   HtmlContent = message
};
msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
```

Another question,
If I changed email name ("Joe@contoso.com") and send email, The message sends by Joe. If I change the email address to microsoft, it sends email on behalf of microsoft why ?.

```
From = new EmailAddress("Joe@contoso.com", "Joe Smith"),
```

or

```
From = new EmailAddress("Joe@microsoft.com", "Microsoft"),
```

Okay I know SendGridKey stores SendGrid Api key but what does "SendGridUser" do ?

```
public class AuthMessageSenderOptions
{
    public string SendGridUser { get; set; }
    public string SendGridKey { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key that you're using to connect is unique to you.  This is why it should be kept secret.  Sendgrid identifies you through the API key instead of an email/password combination.

Comment: But isn't that a security issue? Wouldn't I send an email on behalf of that person after typing the email address I want?

Comment: If you're connecting to sendgrid with your API key, then all the emails being sent out are associated with your sendgrid account.  You can send emails specifying the sender as whomever, but mail services will typically create a message along the lines of "this email does not appear to come from who the sender claims to be".  The email would have been sent via sendgrid (and your sendgrid account) and not the person's service whose email you are using.

Comment: Well, what does "SendGridUser" do ? on this sample code.